# XHR requests with JSON vs. urlencoded: performance and security

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, urlencode, body-parser

I'm having xhr requests with data like name=John username=JohnTheGreat. In this case I can send an xhr with content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded:

```
'name=John&username=JohnTheGreat'
```

Or I can use content-type: application/json:

```
'{"name"="John","username"="JohnTheGreat"}'
```

On the server side(I use a nodejs server with express), for both cases I use the body-parser to parse the data.

1)Which of the two will be parsed faster?
I guess it would be Json since it apparently would involve just a string concatenation and an eval, while the urlencoded string seems to imply lots of string manipulations.
2)Which of the two is more secure to use for these cases? And in general, what are their security issues in modern browsers, if any? (Can, e.g., a user write as his name some script which, when being parsed will be executed?)

Comment: I would guess that JSON would be faster as it's already an object, but the difference might be negligible. Security is another matter and neither has a benefit in this regard.